# Not able to get the attributes of serial port config

Tags: c, linux, termios

Helo, I have been trying to retrieve the configuration of serial port using tcgetattr and I am able to get the correct values at first instance. When I change the values of corresponding parameters return values I get are repeat of previous returns. If ayone knows please help. I tried this when serial port connection was active and working.

```
#include<termios.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>

char *baudQuery(speed_t speed){
    static char   SPEED[20];
    switch (speed){
        case B4800:
            strcpy(SPEED, "B4800");
            return SPEED;
            break;
        case B9600:
            strcpy(SPEED, "B9600");
            return SPEED;
            break;
        case B19200:
            strcpy(SPEED, "B19200");
            return SPEED;
            break;
        case B38400:
            strcpy(SPEED, "B38400");
            return SPEED;
            break;
        case B57600:
            strcpy(SPEED, "B57600");
            return SPEED;
            break;
        case B115200:
            strcpy(SPEED, "B115200");
            return SPEED;
            break;
        default :
            strcpy(SPEED, "ERROR");
            return SPEED;
    }
}

main() {
    int fd;
    struct termios term;
    speed_t speed;
    term.c_cflag = B38400 | ~CSIZE | CS5  | PARENB | (~PARODD);
    term.c_lflag = ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE);

    if((fd = open("/dev/ttyS1",O_RDWR)) <0)
        printf("Failed to open file\n");

    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&term);
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &term) != 0)
    perror("tcgetatt() error");
    else {
    speed = cfgetospeed(&term);
        printf("cfgetispeed() says the speed of stdin is %s\n",
    baudQuery(speed));
    tcgetattr(fd, &term);
    switch(term.c_cflag & CSIZE){
        case CS5:
        puts("Data Bits = 5");
        break;
        case CS6:
        puts("Data Bits = 6");
        break;
        case CS7:
        puts("Data Bits = 7");
        break;
        case CS8:
        puts("Data Bits = 8");
        break;
    }
    tcgetattr(fd, &term);

    if(term.c_cflag & (~PARENB))
    puts("No parity is used");
    if (term.c_cflag & (PARENB & (~PARODD)) )
    puts("Even parity is used");
    if (term.c_cflag & (PARODD & PARENB))
    puts("Odd parity is used");

    //Get the mode (Only part working correct!)
    if(term.c_lflag & ICANON)
        puts("Mode is canonical");
    else
        puts("Mode is non canonical");
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: If you were to repeatedly run the program provided, one would expect to see the same results each time, as the program is setting the configuration and then reading it back.  You have three calls to `tcgetattr()`, which appears to just be for debugging since you're not trying to change the configuration inbetween them.  Perhaps you could clarify if you are taking any other action with the serial port and what the behavior is that you'd expect.

Comment: As probably a side note, this might be possibly be of interest from the `tcgetattr()` man page: "Care must be taken when changing the terminal attributes. Applications should always do a tcgetattr(), save the termios structure values returned, and then do a tcsetattr(), changing only the necessary fields. The application should use the values saved from the tcgetattr() to reset the terminal state whenever it is done with the terminal. This is necessary because terminal attributes apply to the underlying port and not to each individual open instance."

Comment: Thanks David for your response, I'll try it out and get back tomorrow... Thanks a lot...

Comment: I tried the solution as you suggested but it did not work as expected.
at first instance of running the program I initialize the config, when I'm running it again I initialize to different values, compile and then run. It does not return the initializations I made as output instead it returns the same values it previously displayed

Comment: I'm guessing that your changes aren't taking effect because you're not quite making the configuration changes as intended.  I suggest trying to use `tcgetattr()` to read into `term` before modifying `term`'s contents, and using `cfsetispeed()`/`cfsetospeed()` to set the baud rate.  See if any of your changes stick then.  (As an aside, the parity info isn't being tested quite right--I'm seeing both no parity and even parity--but that could be touched up later.)

Comment: Thank you David, I have used a workaround for the time being. Thanks for your response.